# How to start a Go program as a daemon in Ubuntu?

Tags: go

What is the proper way to start a Go program as a daemon in Ubuntu ? I will then monitor it with Monit. Should I just do something like:

```
go run myapp.go &
```

Are there things specific to Go that I should take into account ?

Comment: if there is no urgent need of recompiling your app everytime you should build it once and run it as it is with other compiled languages. see abbot's answer

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You should build an executable for your program (`go build`) and then either write a script for [upstart](https://launchpad.net/upstart) and it will run your program as a daemon for you, or use an external tool like [daemonize](http://software.clapper.org/daemonize/). I prefer the latter solution, because it does not depend on a system-dependent upstart. With daemonize you can start your application like

```
daemonize -p /var/run/myapp.pid -l /var/lock/subsys/myapp -u nobody /path/to/myapp.exe
```

This will give you a well-behaving unix daemon process with all necessary daemon preparations done by daemonize.

Comment: This is how we've done it at work.  Goroutines complicate daemonization in process.  On RHEL we use standard Sys V start/stop/restart scripts.  Elsewhere you'd want to use whatever the target OS uses...upstart, etc.  On Windows we have a small Windows service written in C# that does the same thing there.

Comment: Thank you. Would you mind sharing your C#-Code, Nate?

Comment: There's also https://github.com/fiorix/go-daemon as an alternative, specifically built for Go programs.

Answer (score 10):

There is a bug report regarding the ability to daemonize from within a Go program: http://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=227

But if what you are after is just detaching from the process I have seen recommendations to either do one of the following:

```
nohup go run myapp.go &
```

or

```
go run myapp.go & disown
```

You can also make use of a process manager, like writing an `init.d`, `Startup`, or using something like [Supervisor](http://supervisord.org/), which I personally really like.

Comment: Shouldn't it be like `nohup go run myapp.go &` so the user will get released from the terminal ?