# Programs have to access to global variables in package

Tags: global-variables, go

I've a package with global variables related to a file open
(*os.File), and its logger associated.
By another side, I'll build several commands that are going to use
that package and I want not open the file to set it as logger every
time I run a command.

So, the first program to run will set the global variables, and here
is my question:

- Do the next programs to use the package can access to those global
  variables without problem? It could be created a command with a flag
  to initialize those values before of be used by another programs, and
  another flag to finish it (unset the global variables in the package).
- If that is not possible, which is the best option to avoid such IO-bound? To use a server in Unix sockets?

Comment: Are you talking about several *goroutines* accessing the global variables, or about several (independently startet) program instances = processes accessing the global variables?

Comment: I was talking about several program instances

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming by 'program' you actually mean 'process', the answer is no.

If you want to share a (customized perhaps) logging functionality between processes then I would consider a daemon-like (Go doesn't yet AFAIK support writing true daemons) process/server and any kind of IPC you see handy.

Comment: Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10067295/720999) for more info on how to daemonize processes written in Go.