# How to create a daemon process in Golang?

Tags: process, go, daemon, fork

Has anyone here written a deamon process in Golang? Can you walk me through how to do that? Useful links are welcome.

Comment: Isn't is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/10067295/6309?

Comment: I checked that link. Solutions described in it are about demonizing an ordinary go program. I am looking for how to fork or setsuid.. etc

Comment: Then you will have to edit your question and add *a lot* of details about the specifics of said question.

Comment: I think it's close enough to a dupe to close. The linked question does contain an answer (in which there's a link to a bug) which describes the difficulties involved in forking/setsuid/etc. necessary to daemonize a go program.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes this has been done. See the [go-daemon](https://github.com/sevlyar/go-daemon) project. Be aware that there are certain problems when the daemonization happens *after* goroutines are launched. See [issue 227](https://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=227) for details.

At this time I'd recommend to use the utilities your operating system offers you. See [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067295/how-to-start-a-go-program-as-a-daemon-in-ubuntu) for solutions.

Comment: For systems with systemd this is absolutely not necessary. For BSD, and systems with old upstart (c5, c6) you can use a small program like https://github.com/fiorix/go-daemon without changing your Go code.

Comment: from https://immortal.run  https://github.com/immortal/immortal/blob/master/fork.go