# Creating slice byte goroutine hangs

Tags: go

I have an upload program that I am working on and I am running into an issue. I have n go routines that handle uploading the parts to a big file. Essentially it will split the file into 100MB chunks and upload them concurrently depending on the amount of concurrent processes you specify in the config.

The issue I'm having is when I create a buffer to read the file and upload the make([]byte, 100000000) hangs... but only if it's in a go routine. (I'm using 100000000 to simplify the upload calculations)

Here is an example.

This works: https://play.golang.org/p/tkn8JVir9S

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    buffer := make([]byte,  100000000)
    fmt.Println(len(buffer))
}
```

This doesn't: https://play.golang.org/p/H8626OLpqQ

```
package

 main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    go createBuffer()
    for {
    }

}

func createBuffer() {
    buffer := make([]byte, 100000000)
    fmt.Println(len(buffer))
}
```

It just hangs... I'm not sure if there is a memory constraint for a go routine? I tried to research and see what I could find but nothing. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

EDIT: Thanks everyone for the feedback. I will say I didn't explain the real issue very well and will try to provide more of a holistic view next time. I ended up using a channel to block to keep my goroutines ready for new files to process. This is for a DR backup uploading to a 3rd party all that requires large files to be split into 100mb chunks. I guess I should have been more clear as to the nature of my program.

Comment: You have a busy loop in your program. There is never a reason to use an empty loop. It's just consuming 100% of a cpu for no reason, and will eventually block the runtime.

Comment: Try to use `select{}` instead of `for{}`. Is not the best approach (you should use channels for this to check when the go routines finish), but for testing purposes is ok.

Comment: Allocating a byte slice in a goroutine is fine as you can see here https://play.golang.org/p/8QawOUTFyb, the problem in your example, as already pointed out by JimB, is the for loop.

Comment: Well I saw the for {} as an example for demonizing goroutines. I essentially have goroutines that are processing files and I needed a way to demonize them.

Answer (score 1):

This program hangs because there is an infinite loop in your code.  Try running the code just like this to prove it to yourself.  The goroutine is not what is causing the hanging.

```
func main() {
    for {
    }
}
```

If you just want to see `fmt.Println(..)` print, then I'd recommend having a [`time.Sleep`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Sleep) call or similar.

If you would like to wait for a bunch of goroutines to complete, then I'd recommend [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18207832/3960399) to that exact question.

Comment: Well I have goroutines that are processing files and need to remain open and continue to remain open. The issue that I'm having is running the app as a daemon and that is what spurred this issue.

Comment: Looks like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23736046/how-to-create-a-daemon-process-in-golang) is a good place to start if you would like to make a daemon.  The main problem is you have to not have a busy-wait loop so you don't waste CPU cycles.