# Run Go script from PHP

Tags: php, go

I have a hosting with a PHP file which gets the request, take a string from it and have to give to Go (GoLang) script. How could I do it?

package main
My GO script:

```go
package main

import (
"log"
"fmt"
"io/ioutil"
"strings"
ivona "github.com/jpadilla/ivona-go"
)

func main() {
    client := ivona.New("GDNAICTDMLSLU5426OAA", "2qUFTF8ZF9wqy7xoGBY+YXLEu+M2Qqalf/pSrd9m")
    text, err := ioutil.ReadFile("/Users/Igralino/Desktop/text.txt")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    arrayOfParagraphs := strings.Split(string(text), "\n\n")
    i := 0
    for _,paragraph := range arrayOfParagraphs {
        paragraph = strings.TrimSpace(paragraph)
        if (len(paragraph) < 1) { // against empty lines
            continue
        }
        log.Printf("%v\n", paragraph)
        options := ivona.NewSpeechOptions(paragraph)
        options.Voice.Language = "ru-RU"
        options.Voice.Name = "Maxim"
        options.Voice.Gender = "Male"
        options.OutputFormat.Codec = "MP3"
        r, err := client.CreateSpeech(options)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        i++
        file := fmt.Sprintf("/Users/Igralino/Desktop/tts%04d.MP3", i) // files like 0001.ogg
        ioutil.WriteFile(file, r.Audio, 0644)
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Learn [ask] before you do so. When asking a question, be [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and be sure to provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

**Go is not a scripting language! It is a compiled one.**

#### Compiled languages

> A compiled language is a programming language whose implementations are typically compilers (translators that generate machine code from source code), and not interpreters (step-by-step executors of source code, where no pre-runtime translation takes place).

**So usage of "script" term is dramatically wrong!**

#### How to communicate with Go program from other programs.

You must build and install your program first. This is easy if you already prepared and configured your Go environment:

```
$go install github.com/user/hello
```

Than you can invoke it from command line since it is installed to OS.

```
$hello
```

If your program should expect arguments use [flag](https://golang.org/pkg/flag/) package to declare it.

```
$hello -name <value>
```

Obviously you can call it from PHP with `system` function or whatever is possible (I don't know nothing about PHP).

Other way is to design your Go program as a daemon and communicate with it directly through a port for example. Your Go program must run continuously and listen for a port. A good [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10068950/629685) about daemonization of Go programs.